# How to tell GitHub not to count lines in external libraries?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In my open-source project, I use third-party libraries I downloaded from GitHub. For example, I put them all to folder `libs`. I'd like this folder not to show up in my lines-of-code count as a contributor.

Here is [what I found](https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code):

> Create `.gitattributes` file in the project's root with the following
>   content
>
> `libs/* linguist-vendored`
>
> to exclude the folder from language statistics (e.g. 80% Python, 20%
>   C++).

But it still counts all the lines and makes the counter of my contributions effectively meaningless (e.g. 42,057 ++).

Is there a way to tell GitHub (or GitLab) not to count lines in certain folders?

**Edit**. To clarify:

The quoted part ("to exclude the folder from language statistics") works perfectly, i.e. if the library I use has 10K lines of JavaScript code and the part of my project that I wrote has 500 lines of Python, GitHub looks at my `.gitattributes`, ignores the folder `libs` and correctly indicated that my repository is 100% Python.

But it still shows huge numbers in "contributors" under my name.

Comment: From the "is it plugged in?" file: Did you remember to commit and push your new `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: @Caleb: Yes, I did. The quoted part ("to exclude the folder from language statistics") works perfectly. But it still shows huge numbers in "contributors" under my name.

Comment: @Leo, the cleanest solution is probably not to include those files at all. Does the language you use have a decent dependency manager? If not, could you use submodules?

Comment: @Chris: I just wanted it to work out-of-the-box, i.e. if someone clones my repository, they'd be able to play with it right away. The thing is that the third-party scripts I use are rather obscure, they don't have release numbers and I can't even be sure they'll be around in a couple of years.

Comment: @Leo, you could mitigate the release versions issue by specifying particular commits (possible with most dependency managers and the default with submodules) and if you're worried about them not being around in a few years you could fork them as a mirror and reference your own copy of each repository (assuming the licensing permits this, which it probably does if it permits you to copy the scripts directly into your own project). I don't think it's unreasonable to ask users to `git clone --recursive` or run `yarn` or `pip install -r requirements.txt` or similar.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to tell GitHub (or GitLab) not to count lines in certain folders?

It seems like the answer is currently *no*. I don't think you're doing anything wrong, it's just that Github currently doesn't work the way you want. [Here's a similar issue](https://github.com/markovmodel/PyEMMA/issues/411) where someone wants committed data files not to be included in the code stats, and from the comments there it seems that that's not what happens. In the last comment dated 6/10/18 there, user *marscher* wrote:

> *I'm not sure, if this not only excludes the file from the language
>   statistic but from the lines a user contributed to the project. Most
>   likely only the first applies.*

That agrees with your experience, that the lines are counted correct in terms of the quantity of code in a given language, but *all* the code is still counted toward the total code in the repo.

> But it still shows huge numbers in "contributors" under my name.

You're obviously the person who added those libraries to the project, so it makes a certain sense that you're counted as *contributing* that code to this project even if you didn't write it yourself. And that points to a possible solution: create another account for maintaining the libraries, test data, and whatever else you don't want attributed to you, and use that account to add those things. That won't exclude the libraries from the overall stats, but at least it'll correctly show how much of the total code base you wrote.

Comment: Has the the situation changed since 2019? Does GitHub allow ignoring dirs from line change counting by now?